# Hibernate Search on Amazon Beanstalk

Tags: hibernate, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hibernate-search, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to create a hibernate search project and deploy it on amazon beanstalk.

The project works fine locally but i have the following doubts regarding Beanstalk

1. I am guessing beanstalk might use multiple underlying EC2
   instances.If this is correct on which instance should i create the
   lucene index directory
2. If it is not possible to create a local filesystem setup is there a 
   way i can use Amazon S3 as the index storage which will be common.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, Did you get any progress on configuring S3? Actually, I am struggling with the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the [Infinispan Directory](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#infinispan-directories) to store the index. This provides an in-memory high performance storage alternative.

Since Infinispan is geared for volatile (in memory) storage, you'll probably want to enable an Infinispan CacheStore; there is one which allows it to write-through to Amazon S3.

Two warnings:

- the S3 CacheStore is maintained by volunteers and had a critical issue which was only fixed some weeks ago. You'll have to use the very latest libraries in your stack.
- the Infinispan Directory just provides the *storage* component for Hibernate Search, you'll also have to enable a JMS or JGroups [backend](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#_back_end) as you should never have two applications write on the same index (the backend purpose is to coordinate that).

Comment: Any example or Tutorial on how to do this,lots of moving parts here :(